# Capturing iPhone's key input?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am trying to write a program for iPhone that pop up messages/information depending on the combination of keys a user press on the iPhone. For example, if a user type a certain key word, my program will display a message (my program will be running in the back ground upon user’s request). Can you please tell me if there is a way we can capture what keys user is pressing on his/her iPhone. Either on a text message or a web browser etc.. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible (thankfully) using public APIs. It might be possible (I don't know) using private APIs on jailbroken devices.

Comment: Well, certainly not an Apple private API, and one would suspect that even jailbreakers wouldn't be too interested in opening the door to keyloggers.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments and answer. It was helpful